# How to concatEagerDelayError in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

How to implement a **Observable.concatEagerDelayError** or an equivalent in RxJava2/RxKotlin2 ?

There is :

- Observable.concatEager
- Observable.concatDelayError

But not :

- Observable.concatEagerDelayError

What i have :

```
fun getAll(): Observable<List<User>> = Observable.concatArrayDelayError(
    // from db
    userDAO
        .selectAll()
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler),
    // from api
    userAPI
        .getAll()
        .doOnNext { lstUser -> Completable.concatArray(
            userDAO.deleteAll().subscribeOn(ioScheduler),
            userDAO.save(lstUser).subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        ) }
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
)
```

I want same behaviour but eagerly for selectAll() and getAll() because there is no reason to wait from db to launch network call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concatMapEagerDelayError`:

```java
 Observable.fromIterable(sources)
 .concatMapEagerDelayError(v -> v, true);

 Observable.fromArray(source1, source2, source3)
 .concatMapEagerDelayError(v -> v, true);
```

[JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concatMapEagerDelayError-io.reactivex.functions.Function-boolean-).

Edit:

```
fun getAll(): Observable<List<User>> = Observable.fromArray(
    // from db
    userDAO
        .selectAll()
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler),
    // from api
    userAPI
       .getAll()
       // --- this makes no sense by the way -------------------
       .doOnNext { lstUser -> Completable.concatArray(
            userDAO.deleteAll().subscribeOn(ioScheduler),
            userDAO.save(lstUser).subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
       )}
       // ------------------------------------------------------
       .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
)
.concatMapEagerDelayError({ v -> v }, true)
```

Comment: I edited the original question with more precision. I don't think it's the answer. Or can you provide a precise example for my case ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, next time, provide all relevant details upfront.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. Can you explain me why refresh database makes no sense ?

Comment: You are creating and throwing away a `Completable` in `doOnNext`. I doubt that it works, and if it does, you are doing something far worse in `userDAO`.

Comment: Call to deleteAll and save is unit tested. But maybe you suggest an other way to do same thing ?

Comment: I'd suggest `flatMapCompletable` instead of `doOnNext`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe better to keep `doOnNext` and don't return `Completable` for `deleteAll` and `save` ?